# Angular import styles from angular library assets

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have build the angular lib named "my-lib" and also including the assets folder where my shared styles sheet files are there. After that I have published this lib inside my npm repository.

Now in my consumer app called "my-app", I have installed the above library using the npm command.In the node_modules folder I can see the assets folder of that lib where all those stylesheets exist.

[image]

My question is what's the right way to import those styles inside my "my-app".

Inside the angular.json somewhere like here "assets": or "styles:"

[image]

OR inside the

**styles.scss file**
[image]

Ignore those red curly underlines

OR

**There is a better approach?**